# Unlock User Accounts in Gnome 3 Ubuntu 12

Tags: ubuntu, user-accounts, gnome

My account is a member of the sudo group on the server, so it should have all privileges. However, when I go to 'System Settings > User Accounts' in Gnome the 'Unlock' button is disabled. What do I need to do to be able to unlock this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this is a bug or the default behavior, but you can try running it as root.

```
gksudo gnome-control-center user-accounts
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's a bug. Your solution works just fine. Thanks!